# Python typevar signature for function that extracts objects of a specific type from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, types, pyright

I have some data organized into the following structure:

```
T = TypeVar("T")

my_data: Dict[type[T], Dict[str, List[T]]] = dict()
```

Thus, given a type `T`, this dictionary will return another dictionary that is keyed by a string identifier, mapping to a list of objects of the type `T`.

To appease my python typechecker, I want to write a function that extracts data from the dictionary when given a type `T` and the string identifier. Something like this:

```
def _extract_by_type_and_id(self, some_data:Dict[Type[T], Dict[str, List[T]]], some_type:Type[T], batch_id:str) -> tuple[T, ...]:

    return tuple(some_data[some_type][batch_id])
```

Then I call my function like this:

```
_extract_by_type_and_id(my_data, MyClass, my_id)
```

The problem is, when I try to use this function, and assign the output to something that expect a `Tuple[MyClass, ...]`, the type checker is still upset, saying that the function returns one of two types: the schema specified, or the generic type:

```
Argument of type "tuple[MyClass | T@_extract_by_type_and_id, ...]" cannot be assigned to parameter "my_class_objects" of type "Tuple[MySchema, ...]"
```

The key here being that for some reason, a union of `MySchema` and `T@_extract_by_type_and_id` are being returned by that function. Is there some way to specify that the function can accept these generic types `T`, but whichever type `R` is passed into the `some_type` parameter is the one (and only one) that the function should return?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Type variables don't work like that. `Dict[type[T], Dict[str, List[T]]]` doesn't mean that value types are connected to key types; it uses a specific binding of `T` from some outer context you haven't shown (or it's just an outright error).

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that my typevar is declared as: `T = TypeVar("T")`. I am still learning how to use typevars so I definitely have a faulty understanding :)

Comment: That's not what I meant. Even with `T = TypeVar("T")`, that annotation for `my_data` is [invalid](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=bddbc9146e879a9121857ab20851217e) unless some unshown context provides a binding for the type variable, and even if there is a binding, the annotation still doesn't mean what you want it to mean. There's no way to express what you want in the Python type annotation system.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using pyright, not mypy, and don't seem to have any errors like that ... pyright doesn't complain about the annotation. But okay, good to know that it's not possible